# Filling a dataset from a sql select string in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

I am currently VERY new to delphi. It is older code, but I need to know if why my code is failing is what I think it is. all the data I need to read is in the tables I'm reading from, I know that much. but I'm getting the following error back on my SOAP call:

```
There is no row at position 0.
```

This tells me that although the data is in the DB, I know I'm not able to read it out. am I using the correct way to read sql data from a db table, in delphi, using the following code:

```
FXMLDocument := XMLDocument.Create;
FXMLDocument.LoadXML(strXML);

// Get WebService URL - needed for saving COG Assessments
strUrl := GetURL;

// Fill Applicant and Configuration DataSets
FApplicant := TApplicant.Create;
FConfiguration := TConfiguration.Create;

FApplicant.Username := FXMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName('appid').item(0).FirstChild.Value;
strFormID := FXMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName('formid').item(0).FirstChild.Value;

SqlConDB.Close;
selApp.CommandText := 'SELECT AppID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Gender, UserPassword, ProgToRun, ReportLang, CompanyID FROM Users WHERE AppID = '''+ FApplicant.Username +'''';
selConfig.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM Preferences';

SqlConDB.Open;
daApp.Fill(dsApp, 'Applicant');
daConfig.Fill(dsConfig, 'Configuration');
SqlConDB.Close;

FConfiguration := CASConfigRoutines.FillConfigurationFromDB(dsConfig);

// Get Program to Run from Data
FApplicant.ProgToRun := dsApp.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item['ProgToRun'].ToString;
FApplicant.Gender := dsApp.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item['Gender'].ToString;
FApplicant.ReportLang := dsApp.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item['ReportLang'].ToString;

// Get Company ID from Data for FNB check
FApplicant.Company := dsApp.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item['CompanyID'].ToString;
```

Should these two lines:

```
 daApp.Fill(dsApp, 'Applicant');
daConfig.Fill(dsConfig, 'Configuration');
```

Not rather be:

```
 daApp.Fill(selApp, 'Applicant');
daConfig.Fill(selConfig, 'Configuration');
```

as it is selApp that is the "select" statement? I don't know enough about Delphi to say if it is right or wrong, but can someone maybe assist in telling me why I'm getting a record count of 0 if I know for a fact, my data is in the DB?

Thanks!

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/

Comment: https://lp.embarcadero.com/Object-Pascal-Handbook-2021